# Пропали стили при развертывании 2 приложений

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

Во-общем, развернул 2 приложения на 1 VDS:

Файл **myproject**

> /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
server {
    listen MY_PORT;
    server_name MY_IP;

        location /
        {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/MY_USER/MY_PROJECT1/myproject.sock;
        }

        location /URL_MY_APP2/ {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/home/MY_USER/MY_PROJECT2/myproject.sock;
        }
}
```

сделал ссылку через:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Файл **myproject.service** и **MY_APP2.service** (аналогичны, различие только в названиях приложений *MY_APP1 --> MY_APP2*)

> /etc/systemd/system/

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn instanse to serve MY_APP1
After=network.target

[Service]
User=MY_USER
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/MY_USER/MY_APP1
Environment="PATH=/home/MY_USER/MY_APP1/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/MY_USER/MY_APP1/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Ну и стартанул через:

```
sudo systemctl start MY_APP2
sudo systemctl enable MY_APP2
sudo systemctl status MY_APP2
```

Во-общем, все запустилось и работает только теперь у 2го проекта исчезли стили, т.к. к ним доступ шел через:

```
.. href='/static/.....'
```

Я так понимаю, что надо создать **переменную-домен** и помещать ее перед **/static** и в зависимости от того, находится приложение по адресу **URL_MY_APP2** или сразу в корне менять значение.

**Верно мое предположение, или что-то надо добавить в настройках?**

Answer (score 0):

Подключайте стили без начального слэша и добавьте [base url](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) в html коде.
Для приложения 1 base-url будет `/`, а для приложения 2 `/URL_MY_APP2/`

Comment: не, так не работает. Я пробовал. Я решил эту проблему созданием приложений на разных портах: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1403929/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-1-ip-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b2-nginx