# Как заставить работать 2 приложения на 1 ip и разных портах в Nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, virtual-hosts

Предположим, что VDS на IP: 192.192.192.192. Я настроил приложения следующим образом:

> файл: /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_app1

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.192.192.192;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/MY_USER/MY_APP1/MY_APP1.sock;
    }
}
```

> файл: /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_app2

```
server {
    listen 81;
    server_name 192.192.192.192;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/MY_USER/MY_APP2/MY_APP2.sock;
    }
}
```

Сделал кинул символьные ссылки в **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled**

Сокеты формируют сервисы:

> app1.service

```
[Unit]
 Description=Gunicorn instance to serve APP1
 After=network.target
[Service]
 User=MY_USER
 Group=www-data
 WorkingDirectory=/home/MY_USER/APP1
 #Environment="PATH=/home/MY_USER/APP1/myprojectenv/bin"
 ExecStart=/home/MY_USER/APP1/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:APP1.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> app2.service

```
[Unit]
 Description=Gunicorn instance to serve APP2
 After=network.target
[Service]
 User=MY_USER
 Group=www-data
 WorkingDirectory=/home/MY_USER/APP2
 #Environment="PATH=/home/MY_USER/APP2/myprojectenv/bin"
 ExecStart=/home/MY_USER/APP2/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:APP2.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Сами приложения запущены на разных портах:

```
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=False)
```

и

```
 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=False)
```

Перезапустил **nginx**, запустил процессы и посмотрел статус. Посмотрел статусы - показывает, что работает, но в браузере когда набираю:

- **192.192.192.192:80** - работает
- **192.192.192.192:81** - открывается стартовая страница Nginx.

**Собственно сам вопрос:** Что не так сделано? Почему 2 приложение не отрабатывает и не запускается?

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:**

Т.к. данный вопрос использовался [в теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1424351/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83-ubuntu-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-flask#comment2538237_1424351) и чтобы не нарушать целостность данных внесу пояснение к закомментированной строке **Environment** - как я понял из обсуждения [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1424351/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83-ubuntu-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-flask#comment2538237_1424351), что этот параметр лучше не указывать, чтобы оставить все по умолчанию и потом вручную не приходилось прописывать пути к сторонним переменным окружения.

Comment: Не забыли разрешить порт 81 в настройках межсетевого экрана или типа того?

Comment: @andreymal, да, я забыл его открыть. Но сейчас открыл и вместо работы 2го приложения наблюдаю стартовую страницу Nginx

Comment: @andreymal, во-общем, как оказалось - я в вопросе все правильно написал и конфигурация - рабочая.
Не работало как оказалось по 2 причинам:
1) Это был действительно не открытый порт 81
2) в вопросе я правильно конфиг указал, а на самом деле конфиг не правильно написан был у меня в надстройках: **location /** --> **location /link_name/**
--
Оставлю вопрос, если кто надумает реализовать 2 приложения на 1 IP и и разных портах. Пусть используют.