# Как запустить консольную команду Ubuntu внутри Flask?

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

Написал тестовую функцию просмотра каталога:

```
def comand_ls_a():
    MyOut = subprocess.Popen(['/home/APP_USER/APP_FOLDER', 'ls', '-a', '.'],
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    stdout, stderr = MyOut.communicate()
    print(stdout)
    print(stderr)

    return 'REZULT:\n' + stdout + stderr
```

Вызвал ее в роутинге:

```
    @MY_APP.route('/test_func', methods=['POST'])
    def test_func():
        return jsonify({'data': newd_dir_and_txt()})
```

В постмане ответ:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or
    there is an error in the application.</p>
```

На самом сервере ошибка:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/APP_USER/APP_FOLDER'
```

Да. понимаю, что в доступе отказано. Но как разрешить доступ? Или как-то по другому надо это делать?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ для ganz:

Если сделать так:

```
import os
def comand_ls_a():
    result = os.system('com > out.txgt')
    return 'REZULT:\n' + str(result)
```

то выводит:

```
{
    "data": "REZULT:\n32512"
}
```

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ #2:
Покапался еще в инете и такое сделал:

```
def comand_ls_a():
    proc1 = subprocess.run('ls -a', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, encoding='utf-8',
                            cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),)

    proc2 = subprocess.run('id', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True,
                           cwd=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),
                           encoding='utf-8')
    return {
        'ls -a': proc1.stdout,
        'id': proc2.stdout,
        'inf': os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    }
```

Выводит:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "/bin/sh: 1: id: not found\n",
        "inf": "/home/USER_FOLDER/APP_FOLDER/py_library",
        "ls -a": "/bin/sh: 1: ls: not found\n"
    }
}
```

Причем как то странно выводит. Выводит с предыдущим результатом субпроцесса...

Comment: зачем открывать процесс, а не исспользовать `os.system('ls')` или встроеную `os.listdir`. В вашем случае вероятно проблема с chmod, выставьте права на чтение и выполнение скрипту

Comment: @ganz, вывод каталога - это просто пример, чтобы посмотреть как работает. Как заработает, я хочу другие команды там использовать

Comment: os.system() - не использую, т.к. мне нужен результат в моменте, потому что в зависимости от него надо будет дальше решать. А os.system() - работает по принципу запустил и забыл...

Comment: @Алексей_Белкин, но всё же что какой чмод выставлен у скрипта? директория не блокирована? имеется ввиду иные программы её используют? `os.system('com > out.txgt')` потоки ввода-вывода

Comment: @ganz, добавил в дополнении ответ

Comment: @Алексей_Белкин ошибок нет? что мешает получить ответ(ы) выполнения команды из текстового файла? я же ранее писал о перенаправления ввода-вывода, то есть ты так же можешь задать шелу файл котрый она будет читать, как будто ты пишишь с консоли, ну бля... ну вас нах

Comment: @ganz, я по ходу чего то не догоняю. Просто в документации ни слова не говорится про права и пути в subprocess.run() - там написано, **что text=True возвращает stdout и в stderr виде строк.**, но когда пишешь: **useless_cat_call = subprocess.run(["ls"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, input="-a")**, то ответ получается : **No such file or directory: 'ls'** КАКАЯ ДИРЕКТОРИЯ ЕЩЕ? В Оф.докумментации никакой информации по дирректории нет!

Comment: Какой сервер у вас? Как он был установлен и как вы в нём запускаете свой Flask?

Comment: @andreymal, VDS (NGINX+FLASK+GUNICORN). Стандартный запуск: внутри wsgi.py импортируется APP и запускается через "if __name__". Сам файл wsgi.py - запускает GUNICORN

Comment: А как запускается gunicorn?

Comment: @andreymal, Вот в вопросе я конфиги показывал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1403929/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-1-ip-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%b2-nginx

Comment: `Environment="PATH=` — вот именно поэтому команда `ls` и не может найтись, вы этой настройкой сломали себе систему

Comment: Кажется, systemd не позволяет дополнять значения переменных окружения, так что придётся прописывать в PATH все системные пути вручную `Environment="PATH=/home/MY_USER/APP2/myprojectenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"` (не забудьте сделать systemctl daemon-reload после изменения)

Comment: Хотя у меня ещё с того апреля вертится вопрос, а зачем вам вообще указывать PATH? Если вы не пытаетесь запускать программы из env/bin без указания полного пути, то изменение PATH не имеет смысла

Comment: @andreymal, я делал по руководству диджитал океан. Получается, что можно не указывать **Environment**? Но у меня же каждое приложение работает именно от своего Виртуального окружения. Или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: Настройка Environment задаёт переменные окружения и не имеет никакого отношения к виртуальным окружениям Python. Переменная окружения PATH содержит каталоги, в которых ищутся команды, и, убрав оттуда каталог, в котором находится команда ls, вы лишили систему возможности найти её (и все остальные системные команды тоже)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо. Я закомментировал строку с **Environment** и мне вывелось содержимое каталога, где лежит этот скрипт! Еще только вопрос. Получается, что сейчас у меня все переменные окружения для проекта будут стоять по умолчанию? Получается, что **Environment** надо прописывать только в тех случаях, если используются переменные окружения, которые не по стандарту нужны?

Comment: Видимо да . . .